# How To Rewrite URL in .htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a site/blog that pages URL as `www.example.com/sample-page` and I want to make it like `www.example.com/p/sample-page.html` For this purpose I am thinking to use `.htaccess` file to write rewrite/redirect rule to do it. So can we make it using `.htaccess`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a support request with Wordpress software configuration. Consult the Wordpress support forums or some professional Wordpress support instead.

Comment: And if I may ask: Have you contacted the author(s) of *Pages with extension* and made a feature request? How did they response?

Comment: @hakre Its not off-topic because I am here to ask help in editing `.htaccess` file that is not owned by WordPress. I mentioned WordPress so that you can know all background but if I will only ask to rewrite the URL then what will you say. If you cant help then can make a false claim.

Comment: @hakre I just mentioned the Plugin mean that it can be done. I re edited question title to make you easy.

Comment: Uhm, I might be wrong, but for me this does not sound like you're actually have read how .htaccess works, researched which directives are in the nearer selection of how to get what you want to do done, then implementing those, testing, checking for alternatives and then asking a concrete question because of some detail. All I see here is that you drop some sort of general terms like Wordpress, htaccess, URL and then "If yes, then how?". Sorry, but, I do not see any efforts here. Nor would I actually knew an answer that goes over "You have to use mod_rewrite".

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever

Comment: Question is re-edited and now also have an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should be looking at the mod_rewrite documentation for apache (the rules in there can be placed into a .htaccess file).

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html

However, for your specific case (which I think is to end up mapping the real URL www.example.com/WP/p/sample-page.html to www.example.com/WP/sample-page), you could do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^WP/sample-page$ WP/p/sample-page.html [NC]
```